# Why do we have limited RAM size?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am sorry for my obsolescence but kindly help me understand this.

Nowadays we have 1 TB hard disk  and much more is advancing(Thanks to Moore's Law)..Still we are stuck with 2-6GB RAM...

My question is: Why can't we make it larger..??

If we could increase it:>

- may be we could play more games
- we could load more applications ..etc

(may be I am wrong too)..

Kindly, please explain to me this confusion...Thanks to all in advance..:)

Comment: Larger RAM means more addressing lines on the motherboard / PINs on relevant chips. So it's physical on-board capacity and chipset support. You can get more RAM capacity if you buy the right motherboards, particularly server or "workstation" boards but they tend to be more expensive. I have 32GB in this box and our VM server can take nearly 400GB so it is possible to go much bigger. That said I rarely use more than 10GB on my desktop. Increase: it'll help with caching, and loading more data at once, but unless you're really suffering it might not make any perceptible difference.

Comment: With 1TB of RAM, with our current technologies, don't expect a long battery life too :). And forget about hibernating.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the whole hierarchy of memory, from CPU registers to memory to disk to external storage (floppy, CD, tape, etc.) as measured along multiple axes: flexibility, speed, cost. At one end (registers), memory can be used for arithmetic, addressing, and much more, and it is very fast, but very expensive and therefore very limited. At the other end (disk and external storage), it is slower, plentiful, inexpensive, but not terribly flexible.

As the gap between layers in this hierarchy have grown, you see caching mechanisms used to fill in the gap in performance, especially CPU cache (faster and more expensive than memory, and therefore smaller), and also cache in disk controllers.

The whole hierarchy is a balance of cost versus benefit. You can always have more memory, if you're willing to pay for it.

There are also limits in addressability, but these are also partly a matter of cost (the extra bits to address more memory tend to be needed in the most expensive end of the hierarchy, CPU and disk controllers), and these limits tend to be resolved as needed.

Answer (score 0):

RAM has two disadvantages over hard drives and solid state discs (commonly grouped together under *secondary storage*):

1. Price
2. Durability

RAM has lots of the first, but not enough of the second.

Comment: FWIW I've seen far fewer dead RAM sticks in my time than I have dead HDDs and SSDs.

Comment: But if you cut the power, your whole data is lost. Now this can be compensated with batteries and other means, but this raises the price.